# How to package feathersjs+primus generated client js?

Tags: feathersjs, primus

I am using feathersjs as restful API and primusjs as websocket connection. Below is the code I am using to generate primus.js file:

```
app.configure(primus({
    transformer: 'websockets',
    timeout: false
  }, (primus) => {
    primus.library();
    primus.save(path.join(__dirname, '../public/dist/primus.js'));
  }))
```

In order to let my client to use the generated `primus.js` file. I have to serve this file from my server. From the client side, it can use it like below:

```
<script src='http://xxxxxx/public/dist/primus.js'>
```

But my client is using webpack to package every dependencies into a few big js files. How can I package `primus.js` file in client if it is an auto generated file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can out of the box but it looks like there is a [primus-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/kkemple/primus-webpack-plugin):

> This plugin allows you to pass in your Primus options and then adds the client library to your Webpack build assets.

Comment: this plugin works on client side right? I think the package should include server source code to generate the primus js file. How does client side get the server code? Is it done through npm dependency?

Comment: No, you add it to your Webpack configuration as documented and point it to the Primus library you created. It should then include it in the bundle.

Comment: Is the webpack configuration in server or client side?

Comment: This plugin one only works for `primus` but not for `feathers-primus`. I am writing a webpack plugin for `feathers-primus` but facing a problem.  I have created a question for that could you have a look at? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42775262/how-to-generate-feathersjs-primus-client-on-webpack-plugin

Comment: I don't think Stackoverflow is the right place for figuring this out (probably much easier in an issue [here](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-primus/issues/new)). I don't really see at the moment how feathers-primus is doing anything that would interfere with using the original Webpack plugin.